# Using SCPSolver in Android

Tags: java, android, linear-programming, scpsolver

I am trying to use [SCPSolver](http://scpsolver.org/) in Android project to solve linear programming problem.
I have downloaded the Jar file and added it to the lib folder. Everything works seemingly fine until I invodel the solve method; I get a null pointer exception.
This is my code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import scpsolver.constraints.LinearBiggerThanEqualsConstraint;
import scpsolver.constraints.LinearSmallerThanEqualsConstraint;
import scpsolver.lpsolver.LinearProgramSolver;
import scpsolver.lpsolver.SolverFactory;
import scpsolver.problems.LinearProgram;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearProgram lp = new LinearProgram(new double[]{5.0,10.0});
        lp.addConstraint(new LinearBiggerThanEqualsConstraint(new double[]{3.0,1.0}, 8.0, "c1"));
        lp.addConstraint(new LinearBiggerThanEqualsConstraint(new double[]{0.0,4.0}, 4.0, "c2"));
        lp.addConstraint(new LinearSmallerThanEqualsConstraint(new double[]{2.0,0.0}, 2.0, "c3"));
        lp.setMinProblem(true);
        LinearProgramSolver solver  = SolverFactory.newDefault();
        double[] sol = solver.solve(lp);


    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
Attempt to invoke interface method 'double[] scpsolver.lpsolver.LinearProgramSolver.solve(scpsolver.problems.LinearProgram)' on a null object reference
....
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'double[] scpsolver.lpsolver.LinearProgramSolver.solve(scpsolver.problems.LinearProgram)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: 1) You have missing dependency. 2) Checking the README.md on https://bitbucket.org/hplanatscher/scpsolver/src/master/ states "3 steps to start (works for Windows, Linux and Mac) Download the SCPSolver.jar and a solver pack:" 3) As the README states different architectures, a look in the `externaltools` directory shows various C files. So you'll have to port it to Android if you want to use that library.

Comment: I did that now I am getting :Installation failed due to: 'INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113'

Answer (score 0):

> I did that now I am getting :
>
> ```
>  Installation failed due to: 'INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: 
>  Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113'
> ```

The standard SCPSolver JARs do not contain native libraries for Android platforms.  The [Website](http://scpsolver.org/) says that the downloadables support "Linux, Mac Os X and Windows".  Android is not listed.

You could attempt to port SCPSolver to Android:

- fetch the source code from BitBucket (https://bitbucket.org/hplanatscher/scpsolver.git)
- modify one of the existing solver build script to work with Android
- run it.

You would also need to deal with any Java(TM) vs Android incompatibilities that affect the codebase.

However ... my Googling didn't reveal any evidence that anyone has *succeeded* in doing that, so there could be technical problems that need to be overcome.

The other possibility would be to **pay** someone to do the porting work for you.  Note that you / they would need to comply with the terms of the applicable copyright licenses.  See the Website for details.

Comment: For reference one of the external dependencies for SCPSolver appears to exist for Android: https://github.com/leonardodalinky/lpsolve-android While it is relatively recent it is unclear if it works or not.